# Eclipse is using wrong .gitconfig file and i can't change it?

Tags: git, eclipse, configuration, egit

For some reason Eclipse is using wrong Git configuration. I have no idea where it got it from. I am running on Windows 10.

I can't change it. I can't remove it? The add entry is grayed out. Does someone now how to fix this?

[image]

It is because the file is marked non-writable. But i don't even have a H drive it was a webdrive before.
Where does eclipse get this information from. My real .gitconfig is under `C:\Users\username\.gitconfig`

Comment: Eclipse reads the environment variable [`HOME` that is used by Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) for that.

Comment: but this is a windows machine? where is HOME then in windows. Dit not se anything like that in my windows PATH system variables

Comment: If i use git bash in windows and do echo $HOME it gives me the correct  echo $HOME
/c/Users/eradgar  that is the correct path. the H:\ i don't know where it gets it?

Comment: If the environment variable `HOME` is not set, the user directory (probably computed via `System.getProperty("user.home")`) is used instead. See [here how to set an environment variable on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/989665).

Comment: Hi fixed the problem by this link: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/922

Comment: So you have set the environment variable `HOME` as I told you in my last comment?

Comment: @MaestroGarcia can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

When I first read this question, I was confused, as I had asked almost exactly the same question a few weeks ago.

In my Windows 10 environment, I do not have HOME set, but I do have HOMEDRIVE (H:) and HOMEPATH (/) set, neither of which are properties I can control.  I use Cygwin (you might have the same).  I got around this problem by writing the following cmd script:

```
set HOME=C:\Users\<myuid>
start /min %*
```

I called it "runwithhome.cmd" and put it into a common bin directory.  I changed the Eclipse shortcut, changing the "target" property, adding the full path to this script as the prefix to the eclipse command line.